# Is there a better way to filter out transformed rows in an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I'm transforming the data in a table, and then inserting that transform into a new table. I don't want the new table to contain certain values from the transform, so is there a proper way to do the following?

```
INSERT INTO #transformed (NewValue)
SELECT func_doTransformation(ot.OldValue)
FROM   OriginalTable ot
WHERE  func_doTransformation(ot.OldValue) <> 'bad data'
```

I've considered doing an `INSERT ...` followed by a `DELETE ... WHERE`, but that seems only slightly less inefficient than calling `func_doTransformation` twice.

Comment: Thanks guys. All three are good solutions, but I happen to be a fan of CTEs for readability, so unless `CROSS APPLY` is faster I'm going to go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a CTE in this scenario.

```
; WITH cte AS (SELECT Val = func_doTransformation(ot.OldValue) FROM OriginalTable ot) 

INSERT INTO #transformed (NewValue)
 SELECT Val FROM cte WHERE Val <> 'Bad Data';
```

Comment: Oh, CTE. Duh! I can't believe I didn't think of that first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can nest `select`s to avoid calling `func_doTransformation` twice:

```
INSERT INTO #transformed (NewValue)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT func_doTransformation(ot.OldValue) as NewValue
    FROM   OriginalTable ot
) x
WHERE  x.NewValue <> 'bad data'
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use `apply` to assign a name to the function result:

```
INSERT INTO #transformed (NewValue)
    SELECT v.newValue
    FROM OriginalTable ot CROSS APPLY
         (VALUES (func_doTransformation(ot.OldValue))) v(newValue)
    WHERE v.newValue <> 'bad data';
```

Of course, both CTEs and subqueries can be used as well.

Comment: Is there any difference between the three approaches, other than readability? I expect CTEs and subqueries to have the same performance, but I am not sure if that would apply to `CROSS APPLY` as well. Would `CROSS APPLY` be faster?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight . . . I'm pretty certain that `apply` guarantees that the function is only called once.  I'm not so certain with CTEs and subqueries.